# OpenCV findHomography should return an identity matrix. Why is it instead returning these unexpected homography matrices?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, homography, image-stitching

I use findHomography to stitch images together. But as I was testing it with already perfectly overlapping pictures I got some unexpected results. I was expecting that the homography would always be an identity matrix and most of the time that was true, but one time it returned a completely different matrix.

I made a simple example with the points that returned this unexpected matrix and I got a different result but again not an identity matrix.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image1_points = np.array([[56., 96.], [56., 219.], [56., 219.], [37., 667.], [56., 720.], [56., 780.], [56., 837.]])
image2_points = np.array([[56., 96.], [56., 219.], [56., 219.], [37., 667.], [56., 720.], [56., 780.], [56., 837.]])

homography, mask = cv2.findHomography(image2_points, image1_points, cv2.RANSAC)
# In stitching.py I get:
#  -23.58183,  -0.00000,  547.67250
# -176.30191, -13.80196, 9872.90692
#   -0.26432,  -0.00000,    1.00000

# Here I get:
#   -2.95431,  -0.00000,   88.10041
#  -28.36051,  -1.38109, 1588.18848
#   -0.04252,  -0.00000,    1.00000
```

So, can somebody explain what is happening here? Is this a bug or some special case that can be worked around?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You are using [56., 219.] two times. Try removing one of them and check.

Comment: The backend homography code isn't working properly because you've provided it with a set of trivial points. Out of the 7 coordinates, 6 of them share the same `x` coordinate. The output is wrong because you can't homographise an image when 6 out of 7 points are on the same line.

Comment: as @zwang mentioned, no 3 out of 4 necessary points for the homography may be collinear

Comment: Thank you! I will try this today and report back. The problem is that the Points are just randomly choosen as the best that were found. But I guess I have to make sure that at least 3 distinct points are there in every points-list, so that 2 planes can be compared to each other. If someone wants to compose an answer after I reported back, feel free!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So now I tested the suggestions by @ZWang and @Micka. Here is an updated version of the code provided in my question with added comments for explanation. I hope this will help some people!

```
    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    
    # Original arrays were the problem occurs. There are enough points, but they lack the property to span a plane, wich is needed for finding a homography
    image1_points = np.array([[56., 96.], [56., 219.], [56., 219.], [37., 667.], [56., 720.], [56., 780.], [56., 837.]])
    image2_points = np.array([[56., 96.], [56., 219.], [56., 219.], [37., 667.], [56., 720.], [56., 780.], [56., 837.]])
    
    homography, mask = cv2.findHomography(image2_points, image1_points, cv2.RANSAC)
    print(homography)
    # In stitching.py I get:
    #  -23.58183,  -0.00000,  547.67250
    # -176.30191, -13.80196, 9872.90692
    #   -0.26432,  -0.00000,    1.00000
    
    # Here I get:
    #   -2.95431,  -0.00000,   88.10041
    #  -28.36051,  -1.38109, 1588.18848
    #   -0.04252,  -0.00000,    1.00000

    # No problems as long as there are at least 4 corresponding points and they span a plane!
    image1_points = np.array([[40., 96.], [56., 219.], [37., 667.], [56., 720.]])
    image2_points = np.array([[40., 96.], [56., 219.], [37., 667.], [56., 720.]])

    homography, mask = cv2.findHomography(image2_points, image1_points, cv2.RANSAC)
    print(homography)
    # Now I get the identity matrix that is to be expected:
    # 1.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000
    # 0.00000, 1.00000, 0.00000
    # 0.00000, 0.00000, 1.00000
```